# why I got this exception in xaml viewer of wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have this in xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="TestTool.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:RecoConfigTool="clr-namespace:TestTool" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>


    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RecoConfigTool:Parent}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RecoConfigTool:Child}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBox>,</TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

</Window>
```

In design mode I always see the error of the xaml file but I can run it:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)
>
> System.ArgumentNullException Value cannot be null.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkType.TryGetRuntimeType()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.EnsureRuntimeType(Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkProvider.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   reflectionType)    at
>   MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.VsReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   reflectionType)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.CachingReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   reflectionType)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.IReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeType(Type
>   reflectionType)    at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrType.get_RuntimeMember()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrMember`1.Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Reflection.IReflectionMember.get_MemberInfo()
>   at MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrType.Equals(Object obj)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)
>   at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey
>   key, TValue& value)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.XamlMemberFor[TMember,TXaml](TMember
>   member, Factory`2 factory)    at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlType.d_*7.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlType.d*_0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.d_*7.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.VirtualModel.VirtualModelPropertyCollection.d*_0.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   MS.Internal.VirtualModel.VirtualModelPropertyCollection.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.PropertyEditing.Model.Properties.ModelPropertyMerger.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.PropertyEditing.Views.PropertyEntryReader.RedraftEntries(IPropertyViewManager
>   viewManager, Selection selection, Boolean attachedOnly,
>   IEventCodeBehindProxy eventCodeBehindProxy, CategoryList categoryList)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.PropertyEditing.PropertyInspector.UpdateCategories(Selection
>   selection, Boolean attachedOnly, IEntryReader entryReader)    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.PropertyEditing.PropertyInspector.RefreshPropertyList(Boolean
>   attachedOnly)    at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.PropertyEditing.PropertyInspector.OnSelectionChangedIdle()

- Updated:

  ```
  public class Parent
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
  }

  public class ParentFactory
  {
      public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

      public ParentFactory()
     {
        var child1 = new Child{Name="Peter", Age=10, Married = true};
        var child2 = new Child{ Name = "Mary", Age = 9, Married = false };
        var child3 = new Child{ Name = "Becky", Age = 12, Married = false };

        var parent1 = new Parent{Name="Adam", Childs = new List<Child>(){child1, child2}};
        var parent2 = new Parent{Name="Kevin", Childs = new List<Child>(){child3}};

        Parents = new List<Parent>{parent1, parent2};
     }
  }

  public class Child
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
      public bool Married { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Comment: What do `RecoConfigTool:Parent` and `RecoConfigTool:Child` look like? Are they generic classes?

Comment: Do you have VS2k10 SP1 installed? [Some folks have had similar errors occur](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/680777/wpf-designer-unhalted-invalidoperationexception-all-over).

Comment: yes, it is VS2K10 SP1 professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue M$ [has already confirmed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/680777/wpf-designer-unhalted-invalidoperationexception-all-over) a Visual Studio SP1 bug. Uninstall SP1 and work happily ever after solved it for me. This is highly unsatisfactory and another blotch of shame on Microsofts gown, but what are the options?

Comment: uninstall sp1 should not be a solution I think because I need sp1. Any other solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This issue has reoccured in context with a certain build of FluentNHibernate in my case. Another way that got it back working was get the latest FNH source and compile it myself. Different Assembly, works fine. No idea what VS messes up, since I didn't even call a single method from that lib, just referencing it caused the crash. As you see: no answers down that road, just different questions...